# Black screen on boot after update to 14.04

Tags: dell, screen

I have a Dell Latitude D410 that I bought used with Ubuntu installed on it. It worked fine for several months.  I updated to 12.04. I wanted to read Nook books on it, so i tried to find the software to do so.  I may have downloaded Wine onto the machine,  but I don't remember.  I discovered i could read my Nook books at the Barnes and Noble web site,  so I did that a bit.  The next day, when I started it, all I got was a black screen.  Right clicking would produce a small box that allowed me to open a terminal window or a web browser,  but nothing else.  I decided to update to 14.04,  which I think I did successfully, but now it's even worse.  I can't even get the box to open a terminal window.  Imma try installing 14.10 from a DVD, since I can get to the bios and change the boot order. I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues jumping from 12 to 14. I'm personally reinstalling 14 from scratch from disk, you should open root terminal using "Ctrl Alt F4".
Also wine wouldn't cause any of these problems if your wondering.